# Java ProcessBuilder: stream closed

Tags: java, processbuilder

I am trying to use the ProcessBuilder to load a binary, keep it in its loaded state and then occasionally put data in and parse the output.

What I have right now throws an exception saying the stream is closed.

Do I have a misunderstanding of how the `Process` works in Java? The binary I try to run here accepts input from the stdin and prints the result to stdout. It should work. If I feed the binary by hand over cmd with input the behavior is expected, but I wonder why this does not work when called in Java.

My code looks like this:

```
public class Run {

    public static void main(String [] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException{
        List<String> cmd = new ArrayList<String>();
        cmd.add("/path/to/binary");
        cmd.add("/path/to/param.par");
        Process process=null;
        try {
            process = new ProcessBuilder().inheritIO().command(cmd).start();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }  
        BufferedWriter writer  = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(process.getOutputStream()));
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));

        try {
            writer.write("Hi\\nhow\\nare\\you\\n?\\n\\n");
            writer.flush();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        String l=null;
        while((l=reader.readLine())!=null){
            System.out.println(l);
        }
    }
}
```

> The exception I get is this: reading parameter
>   file...java.io.IOException: Stream closed     at
>   java.lang.ProcessBuilder$NullOutputStream.write(ProcessBuilder.java:433)
>     at java.io.OutputStream.write(OutputStream.java:116)    at
>   sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.writeBytes(StreamEncoder.java:221)   at
>   sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.implFlushBuffer(StreamEncoder.java:291)  at
>   sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.implFlush(StreamEncoder.java:295)    at
>   sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.flush(StreamEncoder.java:141)    at
>   java.io.OutputStreamWriter.flush(OutputStreamWriter.java:229)     at
>   java.io.BufferedWriter.flush(BufferedWriter.java:254)     at
>   hack.Run.main(Run.java:28) finished 0

Comment: Are you sure you wanted `inheritIO()` for your process?

Comment: Don't write code like this. Code that depends on prior code in a try block should be inside the same try block. There no reason for more than one try/catch here.